# Why are my .dir-locals not being applied even though they are loaded

Tags: python, tramp, directory-local-variables

Still on a never ending quest to get per project settings working for python using tramp and .dir-locals.

Hitting a strange problem when I open a buffer I am asked if i would like to run my .dir-locals.el to which I reply yes, everything applies and I do not see any errors.

How ever they are not applied, if how ever I create an org file and setq all the parameters everything works.

Currently using this minimal example generated by emacs.

```
((python-mode
  (python-shell-interpreter . "/docker:root@hackdev_django_1:/usr/local/bin/python")))
```

Also had this format originally both of which should be valid ?

```
((nil .
      ((python-shell-interpreter . "/docker:hackdev_django_1:/usr/local/bin/python"))))
```

My only thought is that its because its a remote tramp setting I am applying although the files are stored locally.

I can tell the parameters are not set because any python interpreter command errors with a local path as opposed to the org applied version which just works.

Any suggestions on what to check or possible source of my issue ?

Comment: You shouldn't be attempting to *infer* whether the dir-local values are set based on other behaviour -- you can check the values directly. What does `M-: python-shell-interpreter RET` tell you in a python-mode buffer when using that `.dir-locals.el`? If it's set to the intended value, you know that your problem actually lies elsewhere.

Comment: Also, what does an org file have to do with this? Maybe you are executing python scripts via org babel, but without details it's a strange comparison to make. If you are going to compare using dir-locals with setting variables manually, I would expect you to be testing both approaches in the *same* mode.

Comment: Okay this has confused me even more now, running M-: python-shell-interpreter on the current buffer shows the correct value but its definitely not using that value as I get a my local project location in the debug.

Comment: no real significance to the org file other than I use it to test emacs lisp snippets by loading and running the block between saves for testing. In this instance executing `(setq python-shell-interpreter "/docker:root@hackdev_django_1:/usr/local/bin/python")` makes everything work which is very perculiar.

Comment: I suspect that the code which is *using* `python-shell-interpreter` is not running in the context of a buffer which has that directory-local (buffer-local) value.  If you're setting the *global* value of that variable in your org file, that would corroborate this theory.

Comment: had not considered that, will try later but makes sense the temporary buffer itself may not be under the current project so would not have the dir-locals applied.

Comment: your spot on with what you said, the buffer I launch the command from has the `dir-local` set but the spawned buffer which has a path in the same folder as the `dir-locals` file has a different value not sure why or how to resolve how ever.

Comment: What is the name or the command (or commands) in question?  (And for clarity, which python mode are we talking about? There are two which are commonly used.)

Comment: The solution may be to have `hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer` called for the spawned buffer, but that might depend on other factors. If you're testing that, make sure you've targeted the spawned buffer's major mode in your dir-locals. This might also warrant an upstream bug report / feature request.

Comment: Currently I am using djangonaut https://github.com/proofit404/djangonaut which uses the pythonic library under the hood to execute the commands.

Comment: So with the issue being raised over there, and the problem not really being what you thought it was when you asked the question, I suspect this one should be closed?

Comment: Agreed, I learn't a thing or two about dir-locals so it was still helpful for me thanks :)